# Flutter model loops when running fromJson function

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, http, mobile

I am trying to get articles from an API, specifically this one: https://api.spaceflightnewsapi.net/v3/articles.

I have created a model with a factory method to code json values into model properties like so:

```dart
factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(
      id: json['id'] ?? '',
      title: json['title'] ?? '',
      url: json['url'] ?? '',
      imageUrl: json['imageUrl'] ?? '',
      newsSite: json['newsSite'] ?? '',
      summary: json['summary'] ?? '',
      publishedAt: json['publishedAt'] ?? '',
      updatedAt: json['updatedAt'] ?? '',
      isFavourite: false,
    );
  }
```

I get data from the API in my stateful widget like so:

```dart
  late Future<List<Article>> futureArticles;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureArticles = getArticles();
  }

  static Future<List<Article>> getArticles() async {
    const articlesUrl = "https://api.spaceflightnewsapi.net/v3/articles";
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(articlesUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      final body = json.decode(response.body);

      return body.map<Article>(Article.fromJson(body)).toList();
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Article>>(
        future: futureArticles,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final articles = snapshot.data!;
            return buildArticles(articles);
          } else {
            return const Text("No article data.");
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

The problem is that I always get "No article data." message, the snapshot in FutureBuilder is empty. When I printed the body that I get from the API, it contains correct json values, but whenever I run this line after I get the body to map it to the model: `return body.map<Article>(Article.fromJson(body)).toList()` it gets stuck and it even looks like it loops infinitely because I cannot print anything after that line.

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`List.map` doesn't work that way. When you use `json.decode`, `body` is `List<dynamic>` type so it can't be used in `fromJson` method. You can simply do it like this.

```
body.map<Article>((dynamic b) => Article.fromJson(b)).toList()
```

Here is `dart's map` function tutorial for you to look up.

https://www.bezkoder.com/dart-convert-list-map/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xWVWDvmqeU